# Why can't the imlgy background remover find the resource metadata?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ocr

I am trying to use the imgly/background-removal package in node.js. However, I keep getting this error:

Error: Resource metadata not found. Ensure that the config.publicPath is configured correctly.

at loadAsBlob (C:\Users\name\OCR\node_modules@imgly\background-removal\dist\index.cjs:191:11)

at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

at async initInference (C:\Users\name\OCR\node_modules@imgly\background-removal\dist\index.cjs:506:16)

at async removeBackground (C:\Users\name\OCR\node_modules@imgly\background-removal\dist\index.cjs:540:31)

Here is my relevant client side code where I make the ajax request to my server.

```
function sendFile() {
  let thePic = document.getElementById("img").files[0]; //This is a file object
  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('thePic', thePic);
  let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
      let imgTag = document.createElement("img");
      imgTag.src = this.responseText;
      document.body.appendChild(imgTag);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/getNewImg", false);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhttp.send(fd);
}
```

Here is my relevant server code.

```
const removeBackground = require('@imgly/background-removal').removeBackground;

const public_path = 'https://unpkg.com/browse/@imgly/background-removal@1.0.6/dist/';
let config =  {
  publicPath: public_path,
};

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    
    res.sendFile(__dirname  + '/views/index.html');
});

app.post('/getNewImg', (req, res) => {
    let img = req.body.thePic;
    removeBackground(img, config).then(function(imgNew) {
        let imgNewURL = URL.createObjectURL(imgNew);
        res.send(imgNewURL);
    });
});
```

I don't know what the problem could be. Could there be something wrong with that URL?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the browser version of background-removal with NodeJS

Try again with

```
npm install @imgly/background-removal-node
```